# Connecting to google datastore emulator with ASP.NET Core application

Tags: google-app-engine, asp.net-core, google-cloud-datastore, google-cloud-platform, app-engine-flexible

I am trying to configure the datastore emulator locally(running on windows) for development and testing as far as updating indexes in the cloud takes a lot of time. I am going step by step through this [guide](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/tools/datastore-emulator):

1. gcloud beta emulators datastore start
2. Should configure environment variables: just writing manually line by line **set VARIABLE_NAME=VARIABLE_VALUE**
3. Trying to access localhost:8081 - returns **Ok**
4. Trying to access localhost:8081/datastore - returns **Not found**
5. Restarted application locally and trying some operations on datastore: all changes are applied on the cloud, not locally...

Comment: Did you place the localhost:8081/datastore address in a browser? What is the expected output? Have you run the gcloud beta emulators datastore start command? Have you set the environment variables with export DATASTORE_EMULATOR_HOST=localhost:8432 or similar? Which code lines try to access the datastore? You may check the "Running the Cloud Datastore Emulator" page: https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/tools/datastore-emulator

Comment: @George, please notice 1,2...5 steps mentioned in my question, I've done all those. And yes I've been guided by this page: https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/tools/datastore-emulator

Comment: How does your code access the datastore emulator, exactly? A few lines may clarify the matter.

Comment: My code knows nothing about emulator, I perform standard connection to datastore and it works fine with cloud datastore, the thing is that after configuring emulator and setting new global config variables the same code that worked with cloud datastore should start working with datastore emulator and it doesn't, please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: Your code should be aware of the environment with statements such as emulator_dataset = os.getenv(GCD_DATASET).

Comment: The reason is that the set VARIABLE_NAME=VARIABLE_VALUE sets the env variable for the running process only. So when you run the asp.net core application the env variable is blank.

Comment: I want to further point out that setting the environment variables correctly does not work either because of a bug - https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/162165578. So skjagini's answer below is the way to go.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have followed the same steps, but couldn't get it working unless I provided explicit instructions to DataStore's Create call.

You need to differentiate whether your code is running in GCP vs Local.

If you are in local environment, you need to create DataStoreDB as follows.

```
DatastoreDb db = DatastoreDb.Create(projectId, string.Empty, new DatastoreClientImpl(
                new Datastore.DatastoreClient(
                    new Channel("localhost", 8081, ChannelCredentials.Insecure)), new DatastoreSettings()));
```

I am still exploring if you could do without initializing specifically to localhost

Answer (score 0):

You can use the DatastoreDbBuilder to force the datastore to connect to the emulator:

```
private DatastoreDb _datastoreDb = new DatastoreDbBuilder
    {
        EmulatorDetection = EmulatorDetection.EmulatorOnly
    }.Build();
```